# Flexcontainer with overflow scroll

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I have trouble flexcontainer div in FF how can i solve this problem ? 
here is example of my code

```
<div id="holder">
   <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

and css of element

```
#holder {
   border: 1px solid #eee;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column-reverse;
   justify-content: flex-start;
   overflow: auto;
}
#content div {
   height: 110px;
   border-top: 1px solid black
}
```

and js here dynamically add div into content

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var C = document.getElementById('content');
    var H = document.getElementById('holder');
    var rowNum = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
    var row = document.createElement('div');
    row.innerHTML = 'Row #' + rowNum++;
    C.appendChild(row);
    }, 2000);

    H.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    var bottomDiff = C.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - 
    H.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

    var oldScrollTop = H.scrollTop;
    H.classList.toggle('manualScroll', bottomDiff > 0);
    if (bottomDiff > 0) {   H.scrollTop = oldScrollTop; }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hello. Please share your code and explain better what the problem is and what you have tried thus far to solve it.

Comment: Hello i shared my code with this link you need to visit this link with FF

Comment: add code here in a snippet not on an external site

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: `I have trouble flexcontainer div in FF how can i solve this problem ` can you please explain better what is the problem ?

Comment: okay, when i have div with `display:flex; flex-direction: column-reverse`. And  some element will added dynamically into that div and it appears overflow: scroll, but it not works in FF

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157361/discussion-between-batgerel-enkhbat-and-mihai-t).

Comment: to me it works in FF . When the divs added go out of the viewport height, overflow-y appears. Isn't that what you want ?

Comment: yes, but mine its not working at all

Comment: That means something else might cause this problem . see this https://jsfiddle.net/hdecwLx5/ in Firefox . Should work. If it does, then other code is causing the problem

Comment: please check this link in FF. https://bug1042151.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=8700740

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting your code i found out that you should add `overflow:auto` to `#content` not to `#holder`

```js
var C = document.getElementById('content');
    var H = document.getElementById('holder');
    var rowNum = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
    var row = document.createElement('div');
    row.innerHTML = 'Row #' + rowNum++;
    C.appendChild(row);
    }, 2000);

    H.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    var bottomDiff = C.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - 
    H.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

    var oldScrollTop = H.scrollTop;
    H.classList.toggle('manualScroll', bottomDiff > 0);
    if (bottomDiff > 0) {   H.scrollTop = oldScrollTop; }
    });
```

```css
#holder {
   border: 1px solid #eee;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column-reverse;
   justify-content: flex-start;
   overflow: auto;
}
#content div {
   height: 110px;
   border-top: 1px solid black
}
#content {
overflow:auto
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
   <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: when div added its bottom of container then to top like reverse

Comment: i saw your fiddle that wasn't what i needed